# jquery to scroll down of section's height with page down key

Tags: jquery

I am trying to make jquery scroll down of just the section's height (which is responsive) when the user presses page down :

```
<section class="intro viewportheight_min" id="intro">
...
</section>
<section  id="page2">
...
</section>
<section c id="page3">
...
</section>
```

css for full height sections :

```
body, html, .container, section {
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
}
```

Here is the js :

```
var ar=new Array(33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40);
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
     var key = e.which;
//     PgUp(33), PgDn(34), End(35), Home(36), Left(37), Up(38), Right(39), Down(40)
      if( key==33 ) {
        $(document).scrollTop( $(document).scrollTop() - $(window).height() );
      }
      if( key==34 ) {
        $(document).scrollTop( $(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height() );
      }

      return true;
});
```

But this doesn't work, it goes at almost at the bottom of the last section.

Comment: Do all sections have the same height? If not how do we know which section height to choose?

Comment: @ThanhTrung yes I added the css, sorry.

Comment: I also tried $('#intro').outerHeight(true) same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adapt your code using this logic. Works on all elements even if they don't have the same height

```
var positionMap = {};

$('section').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    positionMap.push({ height: $this.outerHeight(true), position: $this.offset() });
}

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
     var key = e.which;

     //the current scroll position
     var currentPos = $('body').scrollTop();

      if( key==33 ) {
        //Find next section position
        for (var i=0; i<positionMap.length; i++)
        {
            var e = positionMap[i];
            //found the pre
            if (e.position.top > currentPos){
               destination = e.position.top;
               break;
            }
        }
      }
      else if( key==34 ) {
        //Find previous section position
        for (var i=0; i<positionMap.length; i++)
        {
            var e = positionMap[i];
            //found the pre
            if (e.position.top + e.height >= currentPos){
               destination = e.position.top;
               break;
            }
        }
      }

      $('body').scrollTop(destination);

      return true;
});
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. But I get a few errors with your code

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but you could try and adapt something like :

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
     var key = e.which;

      //Find first visible section
      $el = $('section').filter(':visible').first();

      if( key==33 ) {
        //Find next section position
        var offset = $el.next().offset();
        $(document).scrollTop( offset.top );
      }
      if( key==34 ) {
        //Find previous section position
        var offset = $el.prev().offset();
        $(document).scrollTop( offset.top );
      }

      return true;
});
```

Also I assume that 33 and 34 are the right keycode fr page up and down.

Comment: Why `visible` ? Isn't all sections visible at start?

Comment: @sdespont thanks but this mimics the default page down scroll of firefox, meaning it's scrolls of just a little less than the wiewport...so it doesn't reach the next section fully.

Comment: @ThanhTrung at start, the first section if full screen (100% of the viewport).